# Enter non-breaking space without a numeric keyboard pad?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows 10, I need a way to enter a non-breaking space. (The application, an old version of Finale, does not have a built-in shortcut for the purpose).

And I have to do it on a laptop that does not have a dedicated numeric pad.

If I attach an external keyboard, Alt+0160 (on numeric pad) works perfectly. But I can't find a way to replicate it on the built-in keyboard, which has no numeric keypad. If I use the regular number keys at the top, Alt+0160 does nothing, nor does Alt+Fn+0160.

Is there a working way to enter a non-breaking space? (Apart from copy-pasting the one I entered with the external keyboard, of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### <kbd>Fn</kbd> key

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key generally works only with "alternate" keys. On some keyboards, this includes an alternate number pad as shown below. You can try this on a laptop without these markings on the keyboard, but that may not work.

[image: Keyboard with alternate number pad]

### Character Map

One option is to copy and paste from the Character Map. That removes your dependency on an external keyboard, but that means you can’t use your clipboard at the same time.

To access the character map, click the Start button, type Character Map and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. From there the non-breaking space is in row 5, column 15. Click that cell, click *Select* and click *Copy*.

[image: Character Map]

### Autokey

Another alternative is to use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) and the following script:

```
#s::
Send % Chr(160) ; code for the non-breaking space
```

This would send the non-breaking space character any time you press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. You can replace that shortcut with [whatever else you like](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Answer (score 3):

But does your keyboard have a Numlock key and numbers on the 7/8/9/u/i/o/j/k/l/m keys? (Assuming Qwerty layout)

Engage Numlock then use these keys for the ALT combination. (Note that the 'm' key is used for 0, not the zero key.)

Note that the Numlock is probably a function key combination: on my Samsung keyboard it's Fn+F11.

For occasional use the Character Map copy and paste method may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Take care when selecting the font in Character Map: Few fonts are complete when it comes to Unicode.

For example, "Non-breaking Hyphen" (U+2011) is not in Arial, but is in Lucida Sans Unicode.